# What does the search problem imply about the decision problem?

Tags: complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis, decision-problem, search-problem

Let $\Pi_{dec}$ be an NP-complete decision problem and let $\Pi_{opt}$ be its corresponding optimization problem. Assume $\Pi_{opt}$ can be solved in polynomial time.

1. What does this imply for $\Pi_{desc}$?
2. What does this imply for the class of NP-complete problems and the class NP, respectively.

I am not sure of my answers. For #1, I said that this does not imply anything. For #2, I don't really have any idea. Why would it say anything about NP problems?

Comment: Suppose you find a maximum cut in a graph. Does it help you to solve MAX CUT, which asks whether the value of the maximum cut is at least $k$?

Comment: You could check if the max cut is at least $k$. But, my understanding is that search $\leq_p$ decision. Which means you can claim that if decision can be solved in polynomial time, then so can the optimization problem. Not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Let us take as an example MAX CUT.

The optimization problem is: given a graph $G$, find the value of the maximum cut.

The decision problem is: given a graph $G$ and an integer $k$, determine whether there is a cut of value at least $k$.

If we can solve the optimization problem, then we can solve the decision problem: just compare the value of the maximum cut to $k$.

Conversely, if we can solve the decision problem, we can solve the optimization problem, using binary search.